# How to understand IP version of an IP stored in sockaddr_storage

Tags: c, networking, network-programming, ip, ipv6

I am new at IPV6 and I need to port my project from IPV4 style to dual-stack support style and I am stuck at a point. I need to understand the IP version of an address stored in sockaddr_storage without checking its family.

I wrote a code and tried to use 'inet_ntop' function but it converts all families to each other without any error. For example, it converts "fe80::9110:403c:1f99:eacb" IP to "0.0.0.0" if I tried to convert it by using AF_INET and since it is a valid IPV4 address, my code gets wrong actions.

Please check my code below;

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include "ipv6_util.h"

#define SUCCESS (EXIT_SUCCESS)
#define FAIL    (EXIT_FAILURE)

#define UNUSED(__val__) (void)(__val__)

#define PORT            9999
#define CONN_COUNT      1
#define BUFFER_SIZE     1024
#define QUIT_MESSAGE    "quit"
#define ACK_MESSAGE     "ack"
#define IPV6_IP_1      "::1"
#define IPV4_IP_1      "127.0.0.1"
#define IPV4_IP_2      "192.168.2.254"
#define IPV4_IP_3      "100.100.100.100"
#define IPV6_IP_2      "fe80::9110:403c:1f99:eacb"


void ipv6_util_get_ipadd_ver_from_addr2(const struct sockaddr_storage *ipaddress)
{
    char address_buf[128] = {0};

    memset(address_buf, 0, 128);
    if (inet_ntop(AF_INET, &((struct sockaddr_in *)ipaddress)->sin_addr, address_buf, 128)) {
        printf("it is ipv4\n");
        printf("buff: %s  %d\n", address_buf, __LINE__);
        //return;
    }

    memset(address_buf, 0, 128);
    if (inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &((struct sockaddr_in6 *)ipaddress)->sin6_addr, address_buf, 128)) {
        printf("it is ipv6\n");
        printf("buff: %s  %d\n", address_buf, __LINE__);
        //return;
    }

}

int main(void)
{

    struct sockaddr_storage dumm;
    memset(&dumm, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_storage));


    printf("\n");
    memset(&dumm, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_storage));
    if (inet_pton(AF_INET6, IPV6_IP_1, &((struct sockaddr_in6 *)&dumm)->sin6_addr) != 1) {
        printf("error %d\n", __LINE__);
    }
    ipv6_util_get_ipadd_ver_from_addr2(&dumm);
    printf("\n\n");


    memset(&dumm, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_storage));
    if (inet_pton(AF_INET, IPV4_IP_1, &((struct sockaddr_in *)&dumm)->sin_addr) != 1) {
        printf("error %d\n", __LINE__);
    }
    ipv6_util_get_ipadd_ver_from_addr2(&dumm);
    printf("\n\n");


    memset(&dumm, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_storage));
    if (inet_pton(AF_INET, IPV4_IP_2, &((struct sockaddr_in *)&dumm)->sin_addr) != 1) {
        printf("error %d\n", __LINE__);
    }
    ipv6_util_get_ipadd_ver_from_addr2(&dumm);
    printf("\n\n");


    memset(&dumm, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_storage));
    if (inet_pton(AF_INET6, IPV6_IP_2, &((struct sockaddr_in6 *)&dumm)->sin6_addr) != 1) {
        printf("error %d\n", __LINE__);
    }
    ipv6_util_get_ipadd_ver_from_addr2(&dumm);
    printf("\n\n");


    memset(&dumm, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_storage));
    if (inet_pton(AF_INET, IPV4_IP_3, &((struct sockaddr_in *)&dumm)->sin_addr) != 1) {
        printf("error %d\n", __LINE__);
    }
    ipv6_util_get_ipadd_ver_from_addr2(&dumm);
    printf("\n\n");



    return SUCCESS;


     return 0;
}
```

For this code, I got this output;

```
it is ipv4
buff: 0.0.0.0  39
it is ipv6
buff: ::1  46


it is ipv4
buff: 127.0.0.1  39
it is ipv6
buff: ::  46


it is ipv4
buff: 192.168.2.254  39
it is ipv6
buff: ::  46


it is ipv4
buff: 0.0.0.0  39
it is ipv6
buff: fe80::9110:403c:1f99:eacb  46


it is ipv4
buff: 100.100.100.100  39
it is ipv6
buff: ::  46
```

So I cannot find its original version. How can I do that?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I suspect that this may be an XY problem.  Although there are valid reasons to do so, it is a bit unusual for userspace code to need to interpret the contents of a `struct sockaddr`.  But if indeed your program has such a need, then why in the world would you need to do that without checking the sockaddr's family?

Comment: It seems this way is more suitable for me to change the source code as little as possible but as I understand from your comments, this kind of way should not be a use-case. I got it. Since my question is not a valid one, I really want to learn why 'inet_ntop' act like this and is there any way to do what I want, maybe a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

The address family is just in the `ss_family` or `sa_family` member.

Use `getaddrinfo` to convert `sockaddr` to human readable format.

You shouldn't use `sockaddr_storage` as an argument to a function, use `sockaddr` instead and cast the `sockaddr_storage` to `sockaddr`.

Comment: The OP does say he wants to do what he's trying to do "without checking its family".  In fairness, though, that requirement sounds artificial.

Comment: If I am not wrong, an IPV6 address has 128 bits, I mean 16 bytes. But, sockaddr structure also 16-byte-long but it also includes some additional fields like family data inside of it. So, how could it cover the IPV6 address since there is no enough space to hold it? I am confused at that point.

Comment: The `sockaddr_storage` should be large enough to contain any of the `sockaddr` types. So it's the correct type to use as *storage* for the bytes. However it is very unusual to accept that type as an argument to a function. I mean, look at `getaddrinfo` and `getnameinfo` for example. Since you're passing a pointer, it actually doesn't really matter, because it's basically a memory address. The function's internals can use that however necessary. You could use `switch (sa->sa_family)` or use `getnameinfo` on it without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

I tried getnameinfo function as [Cheatah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/210623/cheatah) suggested and the result is the same as my original post. I mean, it seems I have to use switch-case with sa_familiy at some point.

So thanks everyone.